# Creating set up for Qt Project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-installer

I have Qt application on Lnux. I want to create a executable/set up for this so as to distribute it on Windows and there is no need to install Qt. I have created the executable for this by including all the dlls
but to run it user needs to go inside the folder.

I want such user do not need to go inside any folder,he can directly click the icon can run it. Or such tha user downloads the set up, and install it.

What can be done for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Qt Installer Framework which could be downloaded [here](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt-installer-framework/1.5.0/). The Qt Installer Framework provides a set of tools to create installers for Linux, Microsoft Windows, and Mac OS X.

You can compile the Installer Framework on your own, but i think using a prebuilt one is more convenient. You can see the [Qt Installer Framework Manual](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtinstallerframework-1.5/index.html) for a complete guide on how to make off-line and on-line installers. Creating installers is described [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtinstallerframework-1.5/ifw-creating-installers.html).

A tutorial for creating simple installers for small projects is available [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtinstallerframework-1.5/ifw-tutorial.html).